# python flask_socketio can't get message

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

1. I am trying to using python flask_socketio to connect with postman frontend, but message of "hello" from postman can't read in python.

it's said:

File "C:\Users\w\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\engineio\packet.py", line 65, in decode
self.packet_type = int(encoded_packet[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'h'

it seems that python is trying to decode the message "hello" of the first character as the length of message.I have no idea.

2. Here is the postman screenshot:
   [image: postman screenshot]
3. here's the code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO()
socketio.init_app(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')

@socketio.on('connect')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@socketio.on('my_event')
def handle_my_custom_event(json):
    print('received json: ' + str(json))
    socketio.emit('my_response', json)

@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    print('Client connected')

@socketio.on('disconnect')
def disconnect_msg():
    print('client disconnected.')

@socketio.on('my_event')
def mtest_message(message):
    print(message)
    emit('my_response',
         {'data': message['data'], 'count': 1})

@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(data):
    print('received message: ' + data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,host="0.0.0.0",port=8081,debug=True,allow_unsafe_werkzeug=True)
```

and my postman record:

Comment: Can you share code of `index.html` too?

Comment: just kind of title index.html, it's useless in this code.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to connect to the Socket.IO server using a plain WebSocket client. That is not going to work, Socket.IO has requirements on what you send. Use a proper Socket.IO client and I think you will be fine.

Comment: thanks, I got it. I'm confused of websocket and socketio. They are two different thing. I use (import asyncio import websockets) , that works.

Answer (score 0):

thanks Miguel Grinberg
I'm confused of websocket and socketio, here is right code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets


async def echo(websocket, path):
    # fetch msg
    async for message in websocket:
        print("got a message:{}".format(message))
        await websocket.send(message)


async def main():
    # start a websocket server
    async with websockets.serve(echo, "localhost", 5000):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever

print("server start")
asyncio.run(main())
```